# BluetoothManager's error on Xamarin.Android is Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, bluetooth, xamarin.android, adapter

I'm taking error on Xamarin.Android from **BluetoothManager**. I'm trying scan with bluetooth but giving error **BluetoothLeScanner** property on adapter. Also throws exception on ScanLeDevice method. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
    private readonly BluetoothAdapter _bluetoothAdapter;
    public ScannerBtle(MainActivity mainActivity, long scanPeriod, int signalStrength)
    {
         BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mainActivity.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.BluetoothService);
        _bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter; 
    }

    private void ScanLeDevice(bool isEnable)
    {
        if (isEnable && !_isScanning)
        {
            Utils.Toast(_mainActivity.ApplicationContext, "Starting BLE Scan..");
            _handler.PostDelayed(Run, _scanPeriod);
            _isScanning = true;

            try
            {
                _bluetoothAdapter.StartLeScan(this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Utils.Toast(_mainActivity.ApplicationContext, "Stopping BLE Scan..");
        _isScanning = false;
        try
        {
            _bluetoothAdapter.StopLeScan(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        _mainActivity.StopScan();
    }
```

**Error Text**

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with
>   name='getBluetoothLeScanner'
>   signature='()Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;' in class
>   Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;

Comment: Please show more of your code, please

Comment: I was edited the question. Can you look again? Thanks.

Comment: I am also having this error. Did you manage to fix it?